# How could I create connection between two services in docker-compose so that they can ping each other?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker, docker-compose

I am novice in docker and struggle with connecting two separate services using docker-compose. I need to be able to write in database and read from it. Also, it is necessary to `ping` from each container the other one.

I do `docker exec -ti node-app ping mongo` and everything is okay.
I do `docker exec -ti mongo ping node-app`and get this error:

**OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused "exec: \"ping\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown**

Also, when I start docker-compose I have the following error: 
**Server running...
node-app | { MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [mongo:27017] on first connect [MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED 172.21.0.3:27017]**

docker-compose

```
version: '3'
services:
  app:
    container_name: node-app
    restart: always
    build: .
    ports:
      - '80:3000'
    networks:
      - net
  mongo:
    container_name: mongo
    image: mongo
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    networks:
      - net
networks:
  net:
    driver: bridge
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:10

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 35.158.153.133/80 # my aws public ip address

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

index.js

```
mongoose
  .connect(
    'mongodb://mongo:27017/mongo',
    { useNewUrlParser: true }
  )
  .then(() => console.log('MongoDB Connected'))
  .catch(err => console.log(err));

const Item = require('./models/Item');

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  Item.find()
    .then(items => res.render('index', { items }))
    .catch(err => res.status(404).json({ msg: 'No items found' }));
});

app.post('/item/add', (req, res) => {
  const newItem = new Item({
    name: req.body.name
  });

  newItem.save().then(item => res.redirect('/'));
});
```

Comment: what is the qustion? where is the error ?

Comment: Little known fact,  ping is suid, requires special network capabilities and is a real pita to use in docker.   I avoid ping in docker for that reason.

Comment: That might be because your mongo not started yet before node-app trying to connect to, that will cause `ECONNREFUSED`. When you're trying to ping from `node-app` to `mongo`, it's not working because your `node-app` didn't have ping inside the container. So try to run `docker restart node-app`.

Comment: @ToanQuocHo It is not working and I believe that the main problem is in config file, however I cannot find it. My point is to create smth like bridge between two services to establish their connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first `exec` the container and check if you can ping the other container

```
docker exec -i -t 665b4a1e17b6 bash
```

then in that container ping the ip address of the other service

```
ping 35.158.153.133
```

if ping doesn't work, you gonna have to install it, use this [link](https://superuser.com/questions/718916/problems-installing-ping-in-docker) they are already discussing it.

if your ping works then you know you can contact the other service. then you can start troubleshooting your service.

Answer (score 0):

I just find the answer. `mongo` container doesn't have `ping`. So I entered this container and did `apt update` and `apt install iputils-ping`. Then I was able to `ping` containers from both sides.